# How to extract data from xml in specific way sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

here is my sample xml

```
<NewDataSet> 
<Employee>
<EmpID>1005</EmpID>
<Name> keith </Name>
<DOB>12/02/1981</DOB>
<Salary>10,500</Salary>
</Employee>
</NewDataSet>
```

from where i want to extract data and store in string variable like  this way

```
SET @Data='EmpID=1005,Name='Keith',DOB='12/02/1981',Salary=10,500'
```

so show me the way to extract data from xml and re-arrange or store data in string variable the way i want but please give me suggested sql in such way which should work for different or any xml template. looking for idea. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xmlVar AS XML
DECLARE @vcRow AS VARCHAR(500)
SET @xmlVar ='<NewDataSet> 
<Employee>
<EmpID>1005</EmpID>
<Name> keith </Name>
<DOB>12/02/1981</DOB>
<Salary>10,500</Salary>
</Employee>
</NewDataSet>'

;with yourDataSet
AS (
SELECT
    t.u.value('EmpID[1]','INT') AS EmpID
    ,t.u.value('Name[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS Name
    ,t.u.value('DOB[1]','DATE') AS DOB
    ,t.u.value('Salary[1]','MONEY') AS Salary

FROM
    @xmlVar.nodes('/NewDataSet/Employee') AS t(u) )


SELECT
    /*@vcRow = */'EmpID='+ CAST(EmpID AS VARCHAR(50)) +',' +
        'Name='''+Name +''',DOB=''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DOB,110) + ''',Salary='+CAST(Salary AS VARCHAR(50))   
FROM
    yourDataSet
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work. The query extracts all Employee sub-nodes and concatenates to a string. The script will only work if there's only one row in @tbl though but it just illustrates a way to get the string you want. It's not generic either, that would be a lot harder I imagine.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(data XML NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @tbl(data)VALUES('<NewDataSet> 
<Employee>
<EmpID>1005</EmpID>
<Name> keith </Name>
<DOB>12/02/1981</DOB>
<Salary>10,500</Salary>
</Employee>
</NewDataSet>');

DECLARE @data VARCHAR(4000);

SELECT
    @data = 
        'EmpID=' + N.T.value('EmpID[1]','VARCHAR(512)') + ',' +
        'Name=''' + N.T.value('Name[1]','VARCHAR(512)') + ''',' +
        'DOB=''' + N.T.value('DOB[1]','VARCHAR(512)') + ''',' +
        'Salary=' + N.T.value('Salary[1]','VARCHAR(512)') 
FROM
    @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY t.data.nodes('//Employee') AS N(T)

PRINT @data;
```